# How do I use an acquired Com interface pointer to access the interface?

Tags: c#, c++, com, core-audio

I was able to resolve an initial problem in a previous question and I am getting the pointer to the interface back. It appears that I just had to send an IntPtr variable as a ref parameter and use that.

That leaves me with one other problem that I haven't yet found a clear answer to. Now that I have my pointer value, how do I use it to get to the actual interface? I have defined the C# interface to be able to access COM:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CoreAudioApi.Interfaces
{
    [Guid("7FB7B48F-531D-44A2-BCB3-5AD5A134B3DC"),
     InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]

    public interface IAudioVolumeLevel : IPerChannelDbLevel { }
}
```

This corresponds to the COM interface and is how my other interfaces are set up. The C++ example I am working from sends a pointer defined from the interface:

```
IAudioVolumeLevel* pIaudioVolumeLevel;
getMicrophoneBoostVolumeLevel(defaultDevice, &pIaudioVolumeLevel);
```

On returning the volume setting for this particular part can be examined and set:

```
pIaudioVolumeLevel->GetLevelRange(0, &fMinDb, &fMaxDb, &fStepDb);
pIaudioVolumeLevel->GetLevel(0, &pfCurrentDb);
pIaudioVolumeLevel->SetLevel(0, pfCurrentDb, NULL);
```

Assuming I am getting the correct value in the returned pointer, how do I now set the level through C#?

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the [COM Interop Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645736.aspx)?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Jonathan but that doesn't address the question of how to use a pointer to access an interface.

Comment: I am also in need of extending CoreAudioApi functions in C#. Did you get this working and if so do you have the source code?